# Nested alignments

Tags: align, nesting, alignment

I want to make alignments that look like this:

[image]

which I have done by using

```
\begin{align}
         & \frac{dx}{dt} = y \qquad \frac{dy}{dt} = x \\
\implies & \frac{d^2x}{dt^2} = \frac{d}{dt}\bigg(\frac{dx}{dt} \bigg) \\
         & \; \; \; \; \; \; \, = \frac{dy}{dt} \\
         & \; \; \; \; \; \; \, = x \\
\implies & \frac{d^2x}{dt^2} = x \\
\implies & x(t) = Ae^t + Be^{-t}
\end{align}
```

Of course, it's kinda silly to do \; \; \; \; ... and align them manually. However, when I try putting a \begin{align} within another \begin{align} like this

```
\begin{align}
        \begin{align}

        \end{align}
\end{align}
```

it gives me an error.

What is the correct way of doing this?

---

**EDIT:**

\begin{alignat} still doesn't quite get me there:

```
\begin{alignat}{2}
         & \frac{dx}{dt} = y \qquad \frac{dy}{dt} = x \\
\implies & \frac{d^2x}{dt^2} && = \frac{d}{dt}\bigg(\frac{dx}{dt} \bigg) \\
         &                   && = \frac{dy}{dt} \\
         &                   && = x \\
\implies & \frac{d^2x}{dt^2} = x \\
\implies & x(t) = Ae^t + Be^{-t}
\end{alignat}
```

gives

[image]

Comment: You should use `alignat` rather than `align` --  `alignat` allows for multiple `&` 'columns'

Comment: How should I use alignat? There is this massive spacing between the columns

Comment: Usually, the `&` is used before `=`

Comment: but I also want to align the \implies

Comment: Well, that's not forbidden, of course

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `alignat` for this:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{2}
           &\quad& \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t} &= y \qquad \frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}t} = x \\
  \implies &&  \frac{\mathrm{d}^2x}{\mathrm{d}t^2} &= \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t} \biggl( \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t} \biggr) \\
           &&                                      &= \frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}t} \\
           &&                                      &= x \\
  \implies &&  \frac{\mathrm{d}^2x}{\mathrm{d}t^2} &= x \\
  \implies &&                                 x(t) &= Ae^t + Be^{-t}
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm not sure why you used upright d's when the OP uses italic ones. Even I conform to `\ln` when the OP does on Math.SE, go figure! `;-)`

Answer (score 2):

Nesting `align` environments directly doesn't  work, because `align` environments start display math, so they can not be used inside math mode. Lucky for you, `amsmath` includes `aligned` as an alternative for cases like this (The `t` tells LaTeX to align the **t**op line with the content outside of the environment):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
         & \frac{dx}{dt} = y \qquad \frac{dy}{dt} = x \\
\implies & \begin{aligned}[t]
             \frac{d^2x}{dt^2} &= \frac{d}{dt}\bigg(\frac{dx}{dt} \bigg) \\
                               &= \frac{dy}{dt} \\
                               &= x
           \end{aligned}\\
\implies & \frac{d^2x}{dt^2} = x \\
\implies & x(t) = Ae^t + Be^{-t}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't perform any alignment on the `\implies` symbols. To provide (visual) clarity of exposition, it suffices to perform alignment on the first instance of `=` in each line.

[image]

I can't help but remark that the 5th line seems to be redundant.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document} 
\begin{align}
\frac{dx}{dt}              &= y \qquad \frac{dy}{dt} = x \\
\implies \frac{d^2x}{dt^2} &= \frac{d}{dt}\biggl(\frac{dx}{dt}\biggr) \\
                           &= \frac{dy}{dt} \\
                           &= x \\
\implies \frac{d^2x}{dt^2} &= x \\
\implies x(t)              &= Ae^t + Be^{-t}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```